# How could you know which certificate is used by Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, apple-push-notifications

My Xcode has both development and distribution certificates that it manages by itself.  I don't know how it picks either of the certificates when I build and run my project.  I'm using `Apple Push Notification Service` in conjunction with Amazon.  I ask for a device id from Apple and send it to Amazon where it can be used to publish notifications to Apple and then to my device.  It seems that when I switch between debug and release mode, somehow a wrong certificate is used because Apple rejects the token id that I had just gotten from them and passed to Amazon.  I've read that this could be due to the incompatibility between development and distribution environments on both platforms, meaning that both platforms should work in development or distribution.

I'm sure that the Amazon one is set to distribution because I manage it myself.  But I don't know the token that I got from Apple has given to me by the development or the distribution certificate because Xcode manages it.  Is there a way for me to know what certificate Xcode uses at any given time?  And is there a way that I can specify it for Xcode?  Thanks!

P.S.  The app used to work fine in both development and distribution environments before, and I haven't made change in this regard other than switching between debug and release.